# Groupby and Subtract Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe like below:

```
group value
B      2
B      3
A      5
A      6
```

now i need to subtract rows based on group. i.e 2-3 and 5-6. after transformation it should look like this.

```
group value
B      -1
A      -1
```

i tried below code but couldnt solve my case.

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("Group").agg(first("Value")-second(col("Value")))
```

Comment: How do you know what is first value? What if there were more than 2 values?

Comment: With spark, always remember only to use associative functions. In the above case, (5-6) is not same as (6-5).

Comment: we performed few transformations before so we will be knowing what will be our first value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for me.

```
val df2 = df1.groupBy("Group").agg(first("Value").minus(last(col("Value"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df2 = df1.select("group", "value", $"value" - lead("value").over(Window.partitionBy("group").orderBy("value")))
```

I guess you're trying to subtract two neighbored values with order.